# Problems with ranges in protege

Tags: owl, protege, protege4

[image]
I am having problems when reasoning this ontology. I am also quite new in protege but it seems I am adding float types and the reasoner does not interpret them as float. I have tried with double and the same occurs.
Thank you I advance.

I was not expecting errors at this point.

Comment: you have to assign the datatype `xsd:float` when you create a data property assertion for the individual. Otherwise, the default type of the literal will become `xsd:decimal`. In the Protege editor you would then see the literal being rendered as `0.5f` for example